# Seekbar background image is not as big as enough

Tags: android, seekbar

I have a seekbar and in its background i put a marked picture. here is the background
[image]

but when i add it in my seek bar it shows in this way

[image]

here is the code in a *Absolutlayout*
1-I want it to be biger. The numbers must be clear for users

```
<SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/seekBar1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_x="11dp"
        android:layout_y="68dp"
        android:indeterminate="false"
        android:max="1000"
        android:progress="5"
        android:progressDrawable="@drawable/styled_progress"
        android:thumb="@drawable/thumbler_small" />
```

2-The other problem is: it seems to me that the background is repeating!!! how can i stop it?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Add a parent view to hold backgroud such as LinearLayout, and put the seekbar's background to it's parent view, like this:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/your_seekbar_background"
    >
    <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/seekBar1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_x="11dp"
        android:layout_y="68dp"
        android:indeterminate="false"
        android:max="1000"
        android:progress="5"
        android:progressDrawable="@drawable/styled_progress"
        android:thumb="@drawable/thumbler_small" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks, but what u said makes the pic the background of the whole layout but i want it to be only the background of the seekbar

Comment: My plesure. Add a parent container just for seek bar only. See the answer I updated.